# why this jQuery does not work?

Tags: jquery

I have this table with some styled tds (I put screenshot because the content of td is pretty big)
[image]

Now, I want to add some css to this table so I try to select its td by one if its classes and apply the style like:

```
jQuery(".graTabbedComponentDefaultTabs").parent('table').css('position','relative');
```

But nothing happens....Do you see the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use parents(), not parent().

Parent() will look 1 level up in the DOM. Parents() will traverse up the DOM until it finds a matching element.

```
jQuery(".graTabbedComponentDefaultTabs").parents('table').css('position','relative');
```

Answer (score 5):

You want to use `closest()` instead of `parent()`.

```
jQuery(".graTabbedComponentDefaultTabs").closest('table').css('position','relative');
```

`parent()` grabs the *direct* parent of an element (if it matches the selector).  `closest()` traverses up the DOM until it finds the selector you want and then stops.  `parents()` traverses up the DOM and grabs *all* elements that match the selector.

Answer (score 3):

`<table>` is not the parent of your `<td>` - use `.parents('table')` instead to get the ancestor instead of the immediate parent.

Comment: If that table is nested inside the parent, this will select both, rather than the closest: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Answer (score 1):

Use parents instead of parent:

```
jQuery(".graTabbedComponentDefaultTabs").parents('table').css('position','relative');
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the parent of elements with that class are `<tr>`s and not a `<table>`, your `parent('table')` call will return nothing.

Use [Closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/). NOT parents, as this may select a table that is the parent of that table.

```
$(".graTabbedComponentDefaultTabs")
    .closest('table')
    .css('position','relative');
```